# How to configure nginx for api and front

Tags: nginx

Please tell me how to configure nginx so that it serves a file

**/var/www/public/frontend/index.html**

for all requests except

**/api/**

For api should give

**/var/www/public/index.php**

Tried using

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    root /var/www/public;

    location /api/ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 256k;
        fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    root /var/www/public/frontend;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html?$query_string;
    }
}
```

and

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    root /var/www/public;

    location /api/ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /frontend/index.html?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 256k;
        fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work. Either one or the other works. I know that it would be possible to make a subdomain, but at the moment I need to do without it

Answer (score 0):

The first one definitely won't work, you should use only one `server` block for this case. For the second one, you cantry either

```
location / {
    try_files /frontend$uri /frontend$uri/ /frontend/index.html?$query_string;
}
```

or

```
location / {
    root /var/www/public/frontend;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html?$query_string;
}
```